# Dynamically change the max value of an ipython widgets slider based on dropdown selection using interact

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipywidgets

I am trying to create a function to display 3D images and synchronize them over the slices and orientation.
I have a dropdown widget to select orientation but the slider must be linked to it to adapt its max value dynamically. How can you do that? I have the impression that once you're in the function the slice is only an integer, is there a way to modify `slice.max`?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from ipywidgets import interact, fixed, widgets
import numpy as np

def show(imageList, gridShape, slice=fixed(None), orientation=widgets.Dropdown(options=['z', 'x', 'y'], description='Orientation')):
    if orientation == 'z':
        view = '[slice, ...]'
    if orientation == 'x':
        view = '[:, slice, :]'
    if orientation == 'y':
        view = '[..., slice]'

    plt.subplots(*gridShape, figsize=(10, 8))
    for i, im in enumerate(imageList):
        plt.subplot(gridShape[0], gridShape[1], i+1)
        exec(f'plt.imshow(im{view})')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

images = []
for _ in range(4):
    images.append(np.random.random([15, 50, 50]))
interact(show,
         imageList=fixed(images),
         gridShape=fixed((2, 2)),
         slice=(0, images[0].shape[0]-1))
```